# Proc SQL Select Distinct SAS

Tags: sql, sas, left-join, proc-sql

I have a dataset, `Have`, that looks like this:-

```
ID    Group  Label_T
1763    A     Y
1763    A     M
6372    B     M
```

I want to join this dataset onto another dataset by distinct ID and have a conditional based on the variable Group like this:-

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
  select a.ID
  a.Qty
  (case when b.Group = 'A' then 'Right'
        when b.Group = 'B' then 'Left' end) as Category
 from work.test a
   left join (select distinct ID from work.have) b
        on a.ID=b.ID
;
quit;
```

I want the dataset to look like this:-

```
ID      Qty   Category
1763     28     Right
6372     30     Left
3908     41     <blank>
```

And for the IDs that weren't in the Have dataset to be left blank for the column Category. When I run this I keep getting the error: "Column Group could not be found in the table/view identified with the correlation name b." The column Group is not in the work.test dataset. I think I might have to have the conditional with ID instead of Group but I do I need an additional data set for the conditional then join?

Comment: Since you explicitly only selected ID when defining that data you are used the alias B to point to then of course there is no B.GROUP variable.  If GROUP should come from WORK.TEST then use A.GROUP.  If GROUP should come from B then you need to also select GROUP in addition to ID from WORK.HAVE when making the data for B.

Comment: Do you want the SUM of Qty over the ID ?  Is an ID ever associated with more than one group ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not `Group` column in `work.test` then you should use that column in subquery. It will work fine

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
  select a.ID
  a.Qty
  (case when b.Group = 'A' then 'Right'
        when b.Group = 'B' then 'Left' end) as Category
 from work.test a
   left join (select distinct ID, Group from work.have) b
        on a.ID=b.ID
;
quit;
```

Comment: the column Group is not in the work.test dataset

Comment: then try my query .